# Why does generated IL code start with a Nop?

Tags: .net, il, no-op

I was trawling through some of the IL of one of my assemblies (via ILDasm) and I noticed that *all of my methods begin with a* `nop` *instruction.*

Does anyone know why that is?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The assembly was compiled in debug mode. `Nop` instructions do not do anything (i.e have no side effects), but act as a convenient instruction to place a breakpoint.

**Tip**

If you need a place for an additional breakpoint for debugging purposes, you can force the inclusion of a `Nop` in a Debug build by adding a pair of empty braces, e.g.

```
_grid.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
{
    _isRightMouseDown = true;

    RowColumnIndex cell = _grid.PointToCellRowColumnIndex(e);
    {} //<------ Adding a Nop allows a breakpoint here.
};
```

Comment: @YellPika Yes they do. They waste cycles doing nothing. They are one of the things that make debug builds slower.

Comment: The JIT compiler should optimize them out of the native instruction flow though.

Comment: @devstuff I am talking about Debug builds - they are not optimized out. I would not have added it as a tip if that was the case.