# Why is IL.Emit method adding additional nop instructions?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit, ilgenerator

I have this code that emits some `IL` instructions that calls `string.IndexOf` on a `null` object:

```
MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                                             "Foo",
                                             MethodAttributes.Public,
                                             typeof(void), Array.Empty<Type>());
var methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("IndexOf", new[] {typeof(char)});
ILGenerator ilGenerator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 120);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

This is the generated `IL` code:

```
.method public instance int32  Foo() cil managed
{
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  2
  IL_0000:  ldnull
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   120
  IL_0003:  nop
  IL_0004:  nop
  IL_0005:  nop
  IL_0006:  call       instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::IndexOf(char)
  IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method MyDynamicType::Foo
```

As you can see there are three `nop` instructions before the `call` instruction.

First I thought about Debug/Release build but this is not compiler generated code, I am emitting raw IL code and expect to see it as is.

So my question is why are there three `nop` instruction when I hadn't emitted any?

Comment: Is your question perhaps a duplicate of ["Why does generated IL code start with a Nop?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590382/why-does-generated-il-code-start-with-a-nop)?

Comment: Yay for 3 extra spots to break point your code :P however it is curious

Comment: @Arend I don't think so because emit is not used there, nop instructions are added by compiler to enable debugging. you can only set breakpoints on instructions but imagine putting a break point to the start of a method, you would set it on the first curly brace, since the curly brace is not included in the generated IL, compiler emits nop instruction that allows you to set a breakpoint there.

Comment: In addition to the excellent answer, I'd say not to worry much about nops appearing once in a while. They are ignored by JIT anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ILGenerator` is not very advanced, if you use the `Emit(OpCode, Int32)` overload it will put the entire `int32` in the instruction stream, no matter if the opcode is `Ldc_I4` (which actually takes 4 bytes of immediate) or `Ldc_I4_S` (which doesn't).

So make sure to use the right overload:

```
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, (byte)120);
```

The [lemmas for the opcodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_i4_s?view=netframework-4.7.2) in the documentation specify which overload of `Emit` is the right one to use.

---

In the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/ilgenerator.cs), `Emit` with an `int` argument does this:

```
public virtual void Emit(OpCode opcode, int arg) 
{
    // Puts opcode onto the stream of instructions followed by arg
    EnsureCapacity(7);
    InternalEmit(opcode);
    PutInteger4(arg);
}
```

Where `PutInteger4` writes four bytes to the byte array in which the IL is built up.

The documentation of `Emit` says that the extra bytes will be `Nop` instructions, but that's only if they are actually zero. If the value being passed is "more wrong" (with the high bytes different from zero) then the effects can be worse, from invalid opcodes to operations that subtly corrupt results.

Comment: nice catch! I have recompiled with casting to byte and indeed the `nop` instructions were gone.

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.emit?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_Emit_ILGenerator_Emit_System_Reflection_Emit_OpCode_System_Int32_) of IlGenerator.Emit mentions this:

> Remarks If the opcode parameter requires an argument, the caller must
>   ensure that the argument length matches the length of the declared
>   parameter. Otherwise, results will be unpredictable. For example, if
>   the Emit instruction requires a 2-byte operand and the caller supplies
>   a 4-byte operand, the runtime will emit two additional bytes to the
>   instruction stream. These extra bytes will be Nop instructions.
>
> The instruction values are defined in OpCodes.

And the documentation mentions about your instruction

[**Ldc_I4_S**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_i4_s?view=netframework-4.7.2)
Pushes the supplied **int8** value onto the evaluation stack as an **int32**, short form.

It seems the three extra nops are coming from the int8 instead of the int32.